# How to update Openssl within an Apache Server?

Tags: macos, apache, openssl

I'm having trouble updating my Apache Web Server with the latest version of Openssl on my **Mac**. I've installed the latest version of Openssl through HomeBrew. Does Apache use its own instance of Openssl? **Is there anyway to link the Apache Openssl version to my brew installed version?** Could I just mod the mod_ssl file in Apache? Or would I have recompile the Apache Server altogether?

Thank you!

[Brew based instance of OpenSSL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxh2S.png)

[Apache Server Info, Notice the different SSL version from the Non-Apache based instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxYgg.png)

Comment: You ask one question in the title, and then another question in the body. Neither of the questions are a good fit for Stack Overflow, which is a site for programming and development questions. Maybe you should move it to [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the inconvenience :/.