# checking for OpenSSL version >= 0.9.8a... FAILED open ssl apache http-server Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, apache, ssl, openssl

I've been trying to install apache http server on my mac Machine, the thing is I want to enable ssl feature in it so I add more param inside the ./configure syntax which was

```
./configure --prefix=path --enable-ssl
```

But then it was stopped and giving me this error

> checking for OpenSSL... checking for user-provided OpenSSL base directory... none
>   checking for OpenSSL version >= 0.9.8a... FAILED
>   configure: WARNING: OpenSSL version is too old
>   no
>   checking whether to enable mod_ssl... configure: error: mod_ssl has been requested but can not be built due to prerequisite failures

First I thought I need to upgrade the openssl on mac then I update it and check using this openssl version -a and it giving me this result

> OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
>   built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
>   platform: darwin64-x86_64-cc
>   options:  bn(64,64) rc4(ptr,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx) 
>   compiler: clang -I. -I.. -I../include  -fPIC -fno-common -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB_SHARED -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -arch x86_64 -O3 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM
>   OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/etc/openssl"

but when I retry the ./configure it still giving me the above error.. any idea what is actually happening ?

Comment: Related... [How to update Openssl within an Apache Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38624583) and [How to upgrade openssl 0.9.8 to 1.0.2 with mod_ssl in Apache 2.2.9?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39968670)

Comment: if you see I already update my openssl version the thing is I think the ./configure doesn't notice the changes @jww

Comment: If you check the second cited question, you will see the same problem. If you check its answer, then you will probably solve your problem.

Comment: I followed your second link, and I think it still gives me the error :( strange I already point the openssl prefix with the new one using --with-ssl @jww

Comment: sorry turns out it works because I was pointing to exec file not folder of openssl, but I have this new error which is

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CRYPTO_malloc_init", referenced from:
      _main in ab.o
  "_SSLv2_client_method", referenced from:
      _main in ab.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [ab] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
@jww

Comment: I really confused on what to do :(

Comment: Perhaps you can try [undefined reference SSLv2_client_method](https://www.google.com/search?q=undefined+reference+SSLv2_client_method).

Comment: it works ! I had to change the openssl version using 1.0.2 from 1.1.0 thanks mate ! @jww

Comment: Please post an answer when you have some time. It will help future visitors. After a certain amount of time (I think its one day), you can accept your own answer. Also see [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) on the Stack Overflow blog.

Comment: I believe I already answered my question @jww and I post it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I already installed it it's just that MAC is pointing to the old version which was located on

```
/usr/bin/openssl
```

There are two workaround but first I need to install the new version first, I use home brew by running

```
brew install openssl
```

After that either you want to symlink the old version with the new one (but I did a backup first!)

```
ln -s /usr/bin/openssl path_to_the_new_version
```

OR, create it on /usr/local/bin because MAC will prioritize the app from /usr/local first